# Is there a difference between a = -a and a *= -1 for floats in c++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

For types like signed int and float and double etc? Because, if I remember correctly (a very big if), it's a matter of flipping a bit and I thought whether there's an explicit operation that would do it to make code run faster?

**Edit**: okay, just for floating-point types, the int parts were me forgetting to use my brain, sorry)

Comment: Ask yourself, what is stopping the compiler from working out, from either of those expressions, that it just has to flip a bit, and emitting the machine code that does just that? The idea that the compiler has to do **exactly** what the code says is a common beginner misunderstanding.

Comment: *I thought whether there's an explicit operation* -- Maybe the compiler is smart enough to do this?  Generate the assembly code produced by your compiler and take a look.

Comment: Incidentally the special treatment that some compilers give to negative zero means that this operation isn't necessarilly as simple as flipping a bit.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Examining what one compiler does in one circumstance does not show what the rules of the C++ standard are for all circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-a` and `a * -1` are different operations.<sup>1</sup> Nothing in the C++ standard overtly requires an implementation to produce different results for them, so a compiler may treat them as identical. Nothing in the C++ standard requires an implementation to treat them identically, so a compiler may treat them differently.

The C++ standard is largely lax about specifying floating-point operations. A C++ implementation could consider unary `-` to be a mathematical operation so that `-a` is equivalent to `0-a`. On the other hand, a C++ implementation could consider unary `-` to be the IEEE-754 **negate**(*x*) operation, which per IEEE 754-2008 5.5.1:

> … **negate**(*x*) copies a floating-point operand *x* to a destination in the same format, reversing the sign bit. **negate**(*x*) is not the same as **subtraction**(0, *x*)…

Differences include:

- Negation is a bit-level operation; it flips the sign bit, does not signal<sup>1</sup> an exception even if the operand is a signaling NaN, and may propagate non-canonical encodings (relevant for decimal formats).
- Subtraction and multiplication are mathematical operations; they will signal<sup>2</sup> exceptional conditions and do not propagate non-canonical results.

Thus, you might find that a compiler generates an XOR instruction for `a = -a;` that merely flips the sign bit but generates a multiply instruction for `a *= -1;`. It should generate an XOR instruction for `a *= -1;` only if the implementation does not support floating-point flags, traps, signaling NaNs, or anything else that makes negation and subtraction/multiplication distinguishable.

[Godbolt shows that x86-64 Clang 11.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/Kns44f) with default options uses `xor` for `-a` and `mulss` for `a * -1`. But [x86-64 GCC 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/chK78o) uses `xorps` for both.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I have isolated the `-` and `*` operations here; the assignment portion is not of interest.

<sup>2</sup> “Signal” is used here in the IEEE-754 sense, meaning an indication is given that an exceptional condition has occurred. This can result in a flag being raised, and it may cause a trap that affects program control. It is not the same as a C++ signal, although the trap may cause a C++ signal.